# Get start of process and end of process in a datetime range

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

MySQL query to find start and end of process in a given date range. There can be multiple processes in the given date range. The query I've written gives the start and end correctly if there is only one process. If there are 2 processes, it gives the start date-time stamp of the 1st process and the end date-time stamp of the second process. How can I get the start time and end time stamp of both processes (the 1st process and 2nd process)?

Table contains two columns

1. date_time, datetime
2. value, bit

```
Table 1 sample data
date_time                   value
2020-02-19 00:10:00           0
2020-02-19 00:11:00           0
2020-02-19 00:12:00           1
2020-02-19 00:13:00           1
2020-02-19 00:14:00           1
2020-02-19 00:15:00           0
2020-02-19 00:16:00           0
2020-02-19 00:17:00           1
2020-02-19 00:18:00           1
2020-02-19 00:19:00           1
2020-02-19 00:20:00           0

Sample output
Rowno     date_time                   value
  3.     2020-02-19 00:12:00            1
  6.     2020-02-19 00:15:00            0

  8.     2020-02-19 00:17:00            1
 11.     2020-02-19 00:20:00            0
```

Note: When process begins value is 1 else it is 0. To identiify start time we have to get the first row with value 1 and previous value 0. Similarly for end time we have to identify last row with value 1 and next row value 0.

Query:
-- Identify 1st row with value 1

```
    SET @row_number = 0, @result = 0;
    select @result := (a.num - 1) as prev_rec, a.num, a.date_time, a.value from (
        SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_time, value
        FROM table1
        where date_time >= '2020-02-19 00:00:00' and date_time <= '2020-02-25 23:59:00') as a
    where a.value = 1 
    order by a.date_time limit 1;
```

```
-- Check if value for previous rec is 0 to identify start time
```

```
    SET @row_number = 0;
    select a.num, a.date_time, a.value from (
        SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_time, value
        FROM table1 
        where date_time >= '2020-02-19 00:00:00' and date_time <= '2020-02-25 23:59:00') as a
    where a.num = @result 
    order by a.date_time limit 1;
```

Similarly I look for end time stamp

```
-- Identify last row with value 1
```

```
    SET @row_number = 0, @result = 0;
    select @result := (a.num + 1) as next_rec, a.num, a.date_time, a.value from (
        SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_time, value
        FROM table1 
        where date_time >= '2020-02-19 00:00:00' and date_time <= '2020-02-23 23:59:59') as a
    where a.value = 1 
    order by a.date_time desc limit 1;
```

```
-- Check if value for next rec is 0 to identify end time
```

```
    SET @row_number = 0;
    select a.num, a.date_time, a.value from (
        SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_time, value
        FROM table1 
        where date_time >= '2020-02-19 00:00:00' and date_time <= '2020-02-23 23:59:59') as a 
    where a.num = @result
    order by a.date_time limit 1;
```

Can I get a way to get a solution?

Please forgive me if I have left out anything relevant. I'm asking a question for the first time here.

Comment: what version is your database server?

Comment: is there anything in the table to indicate what process is what?  also, it is so much easier to help if you show output of `show create table yourtablename`, some inserts to create sample data, and your expected output for that sample data.

Comment: @ysth added sample data and sample output

Comment: so you seem to be reacting to the `2020-02-19 00:10:00.           1` row being between the  '12:00' and '13:00' rows.  but nothing in your data provides the ordering you show; if you are sorting by the date_time, it isn't between those other rows.  is there some underlying order that isn't date_time?

Comment: what version of mysql (or mariadb) are you using?  this is very important.

Comment: aside from the 10:00 value 1 row which seems out of place, it looks like you want to sort by date_time and output any rows where the previous or following row has a different value.  is that correct?

Comment: @ysth MySql version is 5.6

Comment: @ysth Sorry there was a mistake in the sample data. The '2020-02-19 00:10:00' is repeated by mistake. I've made the edits to sample table and the sample output.

Comment: ah, and your sample output now only shows rows where the previous value is different.  if the very first value is 1, should that row show?

Comment: @ysth Thanks for the answer. Will try this and reply

Answer (score 1):

To do this in mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2 or above you simply use the lag window function:

```
select date_time, value from (
    select date_time, value, lag(value) over (order by date_time) previous_value
    from mysterytable
) mysterytable_with_lag
where value != previous_value
order by date_time
```

(optionally add `or value and previous_value is null` to the where clause if you want to include the earliest row when its value is 1).

For earlier versions, you can emulate the lag function with variables:

```
select date_time, value from (
    select date_time, value, previous_value
    from (select @previous_value := null) initvars
    cross join (
        select date_time, @previous_value previous_value, @previous_value := value value
        from mysterytable
        order by date_time
    ) mysterytable_post_initvars
) mysterytable_with_lag
where value != previous_value
order by date_time
```